# Quantum corrections to metric on non-linear sigma model target space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, metric-tensor, path-integral, sigma-models

I am trying to make sense of what physicists mean when they talk of quantum corrections to the metric on the target spaces of nonlinear sigma models, for example [GHL99].

First some quick notation. Let $(X,\gamma)$ denote "spacetime," assumed to be compact with (possibly conformal) boundary $\partial X$, and $(M,g)$ the target space. Then the NLSM action is just the Dirichlet energy functional $E$ that assigns to a map $\phi: X \rightarrow M$ the integral:

$$E[\phi]=\int_X |\mathrm d\phi|_{TX \otimes \phi^*TM}^2 \mathrm{vol}_\gamma,$$

where we have used the inner product induced by $\gamma$ and $g$ on $TX \otimes \phi^*TM$ to define the norm of the differential $\mathrm d\phi$.

The critical points of this functional are the harmonic maps. Note that constant maps are a special case of these.

Consider for a given point $p$ in $M$, a harmonic map $\phi$ such that the restriction $\phi|_{\partial X}$ to the boundary $\partial X$ is the constant map with image $p$. A vector $v_p\in T_pM$ can then be uniquely extended to a Jacobi field on $X$, which is to say, a section $\tilde v$ of $\phi^*TM$ satisfying the following differential equation:

$$\mathrm{tr}_\gamma ((\phi^*\nabla^g)^2_{\cdot,\cdot} \tilde v - R^g(\mathrm d\phi(\cdot), \tilde v)\mathrm d\phi(\cdot)),$$

where $\phi^*\nabla^g$ is the pullback along $\phi$ of the Levi-Civita connection associated to $g$ and $R^g$ is the Riemann curvature associated to $g$. Such a Jacobi field may be thought of as defining a "zero mode" on $X$, i.e. a variation that infinitesimally shifts the harmonic map $\phi$ to another harmonic map in its vicinity. It itself may be thought of as arising from a variational principle with action $H_\phi$ given by:

$$H_\phi[\tilde v] =\int_{X} \left[\lvert\phi^*\nabla^g\tilde v\rvert_{TX \otimes \phi^*TM}^2 + g(\mathrm{tr}_\gamma ( R^g(\mathrm d\phi, \tilde v)\mathrm d\phi),\tilde v)\right]\mathrm{vol_\gamma}.$$

Sweeping certain regularisation issues under the rug, we may now define the following inner product on $T_pM$ for a harmonic map $\phi$ such that $\phi|_{\partial X}=p$:

$$g^\phi_p(v_p,w_p) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{Vol}_\gamma(X)} \int_X g(\tilde v,\tilde w)\,\mathrm{vol}_\gamma,$$

where $\tilde v,\tilde w$ are the unique Jacobi extensions of $v_p,w_p$ to the interior of $X$.

For $\phi$ a constant map with image $p$ in $M$, this just gives the metric $g$ evaluated at $p$. Therefore we might regard $g$ in some sense to be a "classical" metric. In order to quantise, there seem to be two possibilities:

We could take the weighted average $g_p^\phi$ over all maps $\phi$ such that $\phi|_{\partial X}= p$:

$$g^Q_p(v,w) = \frac{\int_{\phi|_{\partial X}= p}\mathscr D\phi\, g^\phi_p(v_p,w_p) e^{-E[\phi]}}{\int_{\phi|_{\partial X}= p}\mathscr D\phi\, e^{-E[\phi]}}.\qquad\qquad (1)$$

Alternatively, we could first quantise $g^\phi(v_p,w_p)$ to $\tilde g^\phi(v_p,w_p)$ by taking the weighted average over all the extensions $\tilde v, \tilde w$ of $v_p,w_p$:

$$\tilde g_p^\phi(v_p,w_p) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{Vol}_\gamma(X)}\frac{\int_{(\tilde v,\tilde w)|_{\partial X}= (v_p, w_p)}\mathscr D\tilde v\,\mathscr D\tilde w \,  e^{-H_\phi[\tilde v,\tilde w]}\int_X g(\tilde v,\tilde w)\,\mathrm{vol}_\gamma}{\int_{(\tilde v,\tilde w)|_{\partial X}= (v_p, w_p)}\mathscr D\tilde v\,\mathscr D\tilde w \, e^{-H_\phi[\tilde v,\tilde w]}},$$

where $H_\phi[\tilde v,\tilde w] =\frac{1}{2}(H_\phi[\tilde v + \tilde w] - H_\phi[\tilde v] - H_\phi[\tilde w])$. And after we have done this, we take the weighted average over $\phi$ not of $g^\phi_p(v_p,w_p)$ but of $\tilde g^\phi_p(v_p,w_p)$:

$$g^Q_p(v,w) = \frac{\int_{\phi|_{\partial X}= p}\mathscr D\phi\, \tilde g^\phi_p(v_p,w_p) e^{-E[\phi]}}{\int_{\phi|_{\partial X}= p}\mathscr D\phi\, e^{-E[\phi]}}. \qquad\qquad (2)$$

So my question is:

> Which of the options (1) and (2) do physicists have in mind when they talk about quantum corrections to the metric on an NLSM target space?

[GHL99] https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9901137

Comment: One assumes you know the language in [Ketov's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=9LHxCAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=+ketov+book+sigma+model&ots=yDLUEh868h&sig=v-LqI-WKZachVv6OLzGSnjwaWlU#v=onepage&q=ketov%20book%20sigma%20model&f=false) or older papers such [as](https://www.academia.edu/23761857/TORSION_AND_GEOMETROSTASIS_IN_NONLINEAR_SIGMA_MODELS) ? Your reference is top heavy with excessive notation...